# How do I visit and subtree-narrow after org-capture?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, org-roam

I have a fairly complex journal template which I use with org-roam-dailies via org-roam-dailies-capture. For all intents and purposes, I am fairly certain you can just think of this as `org-capture`.

An issue is that this template includes interactive elements (like checkboxes) which I can't use while in the capture buffer. So my (acceptable) workaround is to capture, visit the heading, then subtree narrow to ignore other headers. Switching to the heading in a dedicated buffer is also desirable because I sometimes spend a lot of time in this template (it is a "planning" entry).

Is there a way to do this in an elisp function? I believe I *must* use the capture functionality provided to remain consistent with my other `file+datetree`-templated captures, but if someone can think of a workaround without using org-capture, I can update the title to reflect the answer.

Comment: Finishing the capture with `C-u C-u C-c C-c` will take you to the note you just added. You can then `org-narrow-to-subtree` with `C-x n s`.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer! I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically, but reviewing the org-capture page, I think one solution could be to finish the capture with some: `(defun my/fin () (org-capture-finalize '(4)) (org-narrow-to-subtree))`, but I think a better solution set up this finalizer for my specific template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NickD's suggestion, I found a way to do this.

In the capture templates you can add a `:after-finalize` function. To resolve the question, I was able to encode the steps @NickD pointed out in a lambda: `(lambda () (interactive) (org-capture '(16)) (org-narrow-to-subtree))`

Additionally, I added `:immediate-finish t` which automates all of the manual steps of my org-capture and brings me directly to a narrowed header.

```lisp
("p" "plan" entry "~/org/daily.org"
  :target (file+datetree "* lots of planning stuff..." week)
  :immediate-finish t
  :after-finalize (lambda () (interactive) (org-capture '(16)) (org-narrow-to-subtree))
  )
```

It's worth pointing out that I could *not* get `:jump-to-captured` working with `:after-finalize org-narrow-to-subtree`, even though this seemed like a cleaner solution.